# Taylor Expansion of Error Function

Tags: calculus, special-functions, taylor-expansion

I am working on a question that involves finding the Taylor expansion of the error function. The question is stated as follows

> The *error function* is defined by $\mathrm{erf}(x):=\frac {2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{0}^{x} e^{-t^{2}}dt$. Find its Taylor expansion.

I know that the Taylor series of the function $f$ at $a$ is given by

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac {f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^{n}.$$

However, the question doesn't give a point $a$ with which to center the Taylor series. How should I interpret this? May I use a Maclaurin series, with $a=0$? This appears to be what was done on the Wikipedia page here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function

Any explanations and advice would be appreciated.

Comment: $a=0$ seems OK for me. I would expand $e^{-t^2}$ in a power series and integrate term by term.

Answer (score 6):

Elaborating a little on Marty's comment gives the following:

$f^{(n)}(a)$ can be written in terms of [Hermite polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Definition) $H_n$:

$$
    H_0(x)=1,\,
    H_1(x)=2x,\,
    H_2(x)=4x^2-2,\,
    H_3(x)=8x^3-12x,\,
    H_4(x)=16x^4-48x^2+12,\,
    H_5(x)=32x^5-160x^3+120x,\,
    H_6(x)=64x^6-480x^4+720x^2-120,\dots\,
$$
You recognize that $H_{2n-1}(0)=0$, which gives the power series for $e^{-x^2}$ at $a=0$:
$$
e^{-x^2} = 1 - \frac{2}{2!}x^2+\frac{12}{4!}x^4-\frac{120}{6!}x^6+\cdots
$$
(see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=exp%28-x%5E2%29)). After multiplying by $2/\sqrt{\pi}$, this integrates to 
$$
    \operatorname{erf}(z) =\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \left(z-\frac{z^3}{3}+\frac{z^5}{10}-\frac{z^7}{42}+\frac{z^9}{216}-\ \cdots\right) .
$$

---

**EDIT:**
Since 
$\displaystyle
\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{-x^2}= (-1)^n e^{-x^2} H_n(x),
$
one can do a Taylor Series for every $a$:
$$
\text{erf}_a(x)= \text{erf}(a) + e^{-a^2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{H_n(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n
$$

Comment: "$f^{(n)}(a)$ can be written in terms of Hermite polynomials..." - of course, since the Rodrigues formula for the Hermite polynomials involves the repeated differentiation of the Gaussian function $\exp(-x^2)$...

Comment: Also: the odd-order Hermite polynomials are odd (and thus $H_{2n+1}(0)=0$) precisely because the Gaussian weight function is even.

Comment: @J.M. And so, one can do a Taylor Series for every $a$: $\text{erf}_a(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n e^{-a^2} \frac {H_n(a)}{n!}(x-a)^{n}$, right?

Comment: Sure, the error function is analytic...

Comment: I would not be able to solve for $erf(a)$ if I were to expand around $a$ - would I?

Comment: @fitzgeraldo, what do you mean by solve? It's not necessary to expand around $a$ to get $erf(a)$...

Comment: @draks What is the radius of convergence of this series?

Comment: Your expression for general "$a$", for $a=0$ results does not correspond to $\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}
(z-z^3/3+z^5/10...)$. Can you comment on that?

Comment: Instead, you get ${\rm erf}_0(x)=-2x^2+x^4/2-x^6/6...$

Answer (score 1):

Context for using the Taylor Series of $$e^{-t^2}$$ to find the Taylor expansion of the ERF function is found at [Robert Ghrist/UPenn's Calculus wiki](http://calculus.seas.upenn.edu/?n=Main.TaylorSeries).

Comment: The link appears to be broken.